# Mysql select If else if query with three values

Tags: mysql

E.g : (select IF(u.username=1, "Male","Female")) as sex this is working but I have three values 1,2 and 3.
When value is 1 it will be return male, When value is 2 it will be return female and When value is 3 it will be return both.

Please help me to find the solution on that.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `CASE EXPRESSION` which is very similar to `IF` but not limited by the amount of values to process :

```
SELECT CASE WHEN u.username = 1 THEN 'Male'
            WHEN u.username = 2 THEN 'Female'
            WHEN u.username = 3 THEN 'Both'
            .....
       END
```

Comment: Yes, note that you could achieve that with nested`IF`s too. `CASE EXPRESSION` is much clearer.

Comment: I know, but I always prefer CASE, looks more readable to me @Stan

Answer (score 2):

Please check this query:

```
SELECT CASE u.username 
WHEN 1 THEN 'MALE'
WHEN 2 THEN 'FEMALE'
ELSE 'BOTH'
END 
FROM user;
```

Comment: Did you copy my answer?

Comment: why i would do that?

Comment: Because its the same as mine 10 minutes later?

Comment: No brother, I did it myself. I never copied that from you. Normally i answer the questions while i am working. So never saw your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Or you use ELT() Function:

```
SELECT ELT('2','Male','Female','Both');
```

**SAMPLE**

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT ELT(2,'Male','Female','Both');
+-------------------------------+
| ELT(2,'Male','Female','Both') |
+-------------------------------+
| Female                        |
+-------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]>
```

Comment: great suggestion, it's simpler than usual `CASE`.

Comment: ... not good, I mean either I'm blind or you don't understand the question, am I ?

Answer (score 1):

I found simple answer for that:
IF(gender=1 , 'male',  IF(gender=2, 'female', 'both')) AS sex

Anyways thanks for reply..
cheers!!!...

Comment: Thats nested `If's`, and when dealing with a lot of them its become unreadable! I think you should avoid that.